# Разница между жизненным циклом приложения и проекта

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Хочу уточнить одно ли и тоже "жизненный цикл приложения IOS" и "жизненный цикл проекта в XCode"?

Comment: предположим что под жизненным циклом ты принимал жизненный цикл ViewController(а), а под жизненным циклом проекта - жизненный цикл информационной системы, то про ViewController можно почитать [тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html), а про жизненный цикл приложения [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

`"жизненный цикл приложения iOS"` - это больше про то, как приложение взаимодествует с системой. Например, происходит запуск приложения, оно отвечает системе что оно запущено, приложение обрабатывает пуши, можете переходить в фоновый режим и обратно, может быть завершено системой или пользователем.

`"жизненный цикл проекта в XCode"` - это про проект и код в проекте, как вы его разрабатываете, как Xcode компилирует и собирает проект, как вы добавляете ресурсы в проект и всё в этом духе.

Возможно, в каком-то контексте эти выражения можно воспринимать как одно и то-же, но если вы говорите с iOS разработчиком, то я бы сказал, что это довольно разные понятия.

Comment: Это верные ссылки? Жизненный цикл проекта https://habr.com/ru/post/129557/, приложения https://proswift.ru/ios-application-lifecycle-ili-zhiznennyj-cikl-ios-prilozheniya/